# Google places radar search with a radius greater than 50,000 meters

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm trying to find all Panera restaurants within a **200 mile** radius of a certain point.

Here is the URL I have been using so far :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=39.52963,-119.81380&radius=321869&type=restaurant&name=panera&key=your-key-here
```

However, I have found out that radius has a **maximum of 30 miles**. Can anyone suggest a quick workaround for me?

Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Open Google Maps and save 8-10 or more points' lat,long value to trigger your request. Then use a loop to find all places within these points. If you want more precise results, increase first trigger points for your requests.

I tried, it works.

Assume we are using php

```
$triggerPoints = array("lat1,long1", "lat2,long2", "lat3,long3",....);

foreeach(triggerPoints as $t){
   $requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$t&radius=[YOUR_RADIUS_VALUE]&type=restaurant&name=panera&key=your-key-here";
   $results = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
   //Do what you want with response JSON data

}
```

**Important: When you choose trigger points, those points should intersect according to your radius value. So you don't miss any restaurants**

Answer (score 0):

Business license with for [higher usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/). 
[Contact Google sales](https://enterprise.google.com/maps/)

Google place **nearby search** maximum 50,000 meters (31 miles) .
if you try enter more than 50,000 it not work proper.

There is another way for find all restaurants in a city. 
google provide **Text Search Requests**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Reno,NV,89501,USA&key={API_KEY}
```

**query = keyword + in +  city Name**

for get city name using `latitude longitude`

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.52963,-119.81380&sensor=true
```

For more information how to get city name using `latitude longitude`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding

for more information about how to use Text Search Requests

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: Thanks Harshil, I had the same thought. The issue is that using the text search will also not return restaurants outside of ~30 mile range. My solution was to gather a list of all the zip codes in a 200 mile radius then run a text search as "restaurants in [zip code]" then compile all the results in one table, and filter just for the restaurants I want. Can you think of a more simple solution than that? Mine seems rather convoluted.

Comment: Business license with for higher usage limits. Contact Google sales. https://enterprise.google.com/maps/

Comment: Use math. Find additional points and cover the 31mile radius using multiple calls with smaller radii.